# Clone and modify `express-validator` chains

Tags: javascript, express-validator

How can I clone an `express-validator` chain and make it optional, without affecting the original one? For instance, consider this example:

```
var checkPassword = body('password').trim().isLength({min: 10});
var checkPasswordOptional = checkPassword.optional();

// Creates an account.
router.post('/accounts', checkPassword, createAccount);

// Updates an account. Only provided fields are updated.
router.put('/accounts/:id', checkPasswordOptional, updateAccount);
```

But with this, both `checkPassword` and `checkPasswordOptional` become optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning chains isn't a supported feature yet.

You can, however, use factory functions that will produce the same validator chain as many times as you wish:

```
const createPasswordCheck = () => body('password').trim().isLength({ min: 10 });

// Uses the default password validation chain    
router.post('/accounts', createPasswordCheck(), createAccount);

// In addition to the default set of password validations,
// updating an account also makes it optional.
router.put('/accounts/:id', createPasswordCheck().optional(), updateAccount);
```

<sub>Disclaimer: express-validator maintainer here.</sub>